# Dynamic Icon content in Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

What I need is to adjust Icon's content accordingly to the available screen space.

If the screen height is enough - I would like to display a bigger image version. If it's not enough - I want to display a smaller version.

Roughly, my screen's content is next:

```
Column {
   Topbar()
   Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
      HorizontalPager(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
          Image()  
          Text()
      }
      HorizontalPagerIndicator()
   }
   Buttons()
}
```

The structure is simplified.
So, `Topbar` and `Buttons` are static and located at the top and at the bottom of the screen. The middle of the screen is taken by `HorizontalPager`. The indicator should stay on the bottom of this part and all other available space is filled with the pager's content.
The issue is that I should have different images inside a pager depending on how much height is available.

Here is what the full image should look like:

[image: full image]

small version:
[image: small image]

Appreciate any tips, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshots are different from what you are asking, do you want to display bigger images or two rows of images ?

Btw, a solution can be measuring the display height with `LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp` and adapt your `HorizontalPager` based on that.
Or creating multiple rows if you want the lines to scroll separately.

Comment: All these 'rows of images' is a single image. In one case it's a bigger image with 2 rows, it another - smaller with 1 row. 
Your suggested solution might work, I'll give it a try. Thanks!